# How does the dual rail qubit conceptually detect erasures for the amplitude damping channel?

Tags: quantum-operation

I think I am missing something in my understanding of the amplitude damping and erasure channels when it comes to the dual-rail encoding.

I have the following dual-rail photonic qubit labeled by system $A$ and $B$:

$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha|01\rangle_{AB} + \beta|10\rangle_{AB} \\
\hat{\rho}_{AB} = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=|\alpha|^2 |01\rangle\langle01| + |\beta|^2|10\rangle\langle10| + \alpha^*\beta|10\rangle\langle01| + \alpha\beta^*|01\rangle\langle10|
$$

and the amplitude damping channel is given by a beamsplitter with the qubit input on one port and vacuum input on the other.

If the beamsplitter acts independently on each system, I can send system $A$ through the amplitude damping channel followed by system $B$.

If the first system passed through the beamsplitter results in the photon being lost, its output state will be $\hat{\rho}_{A^\prime} =|0\rangle\langle0|$. Then if no photon is lost when I pass system $B$ through the beamsplitter it will result in the state $\hat{\rho}_{B^\prime} =|\alpha|^2 |0\rangle\langle0| + |\beta|^2|1\rangle\langle1| + \alpha^*\beta|1\rangle\langle0| + \alpha\beta^*|0\rangle\langle1|
$

Then $\hat{\rho}_{A^\prime B^\prime} =|\alpha|^2 |00\rangle\langle00| + |\beta|^2|10\rangle\langle10| + \alpha^*\beta|10\rangle\langle00| + \alpha\beta^*|00\rangle\langle10|$

So then its unclear to me how you would detect an erasure happening in this case since the $|01\rangle\langle01|$ is in the hilbert space of the original qubit still.

I understand that if neither photon was lost, you would end up in the original state, and if both photons were lost you would end up in the $|00\rangle\langle00|$ state where measurement in the $\{|01\rangle, |10\rangle\}$ basis would detect the erasure. But the single photon loss plus no photon loss case is confusing.

Comment: what's definition of amplitude damping channel are you using here? The amplitude damping channel is not unitary, so it won't send $|\psi\rangle$ to $|\psi'\rangle$

Comment: I was looking at the optical description of the amplitude damping channel where photons pass through a beam splitter with vacuum input where conceptually I thought of this as our input state having a chance to simply lose a photon or nothing at all happens. The math makes conceptual sense to me when you trace out the environment mode or use Kraus operators, but the dual rail case doesn't since it seems like there should be 4 possible output states not just 2: nothing happens, 1 photon loss from one mode, 1 photon loss from both modes

Comment: if you're describing a single photon evolving through a (I suppose balanced?) beamsplitter, you don't get the evolution you're writing. You can't go from $|\psi\rangle$ to $|\psi'\rangle$ with a unitary evolution. If you're trying to refer to the isometric/unitary representation of the channel, that's also different, as it corresponds to $|0\rangle\to|00\rangle$ and $|1\rangle\to \sqrt{1-p}|10\rangle+\sqrt p|01\rangle$. So I still don't understand how you get that $|\psi'\rangle$

Comment: Yeah, the $|\psi^\prime\rangle$ in my question is incorrect it was more of "if a photon is lost in the $\beta$ term here's what I'd expect the state to be". I guess a simpler question is how does the dual rail qubit detect erasures when there is only one photon lost? The output state is given by $\hat{\rho} \to p \hat{\rho} + (1-p)|00\rangle\langle00|$ But to me, it seems like you only would end up in $|00\rangle\langle00|$ if you lost a photon in both modes, if you lost a photon in one mode you'd end up in some other state that has terms like $|00\rangle\langle01|$ and $|01\rangle\langle00|$

Comment: maybe you should clarify what exactly you mean with this "dual-rail encoding". It sounds like you're considering a single photon passing through a beamsplitter, and then you're applying an amplitude damping channel where, to both the output modes of the beamsplitter? Or only one of them? Or something else? If you lose a photon somewhere in the output and there's only one input photon then you have the vacuum state, sure, but I don't understand how this relates to the rest of the question

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I do mean the dual-rail system where the signal is two modes in the dual rail and the other end of the beamsplitter is a two mode vacuum. I've updated the question hopefully to be a bit more transparent in what I'm grappling with. Thank you for your help.